# OCR for mobile photos

Tags: iphone, android, ocr, tesseract

I'm thinking of developping a mobile OCR app to detect words from mobile pictures.
The purpose if only to detect what words are in the picture, the layout is not important.
Also it would be use on very short texts.

I'm currently thinking of adapting tesseract to iphone and android.

I wonder if anyone has had any related experience? What are the limits etc.

Thanks!

Comment: did you proceed any step in this regard. I am also interested to integrate tesseract with iPhone.

Comment: @karim: I checked commercial SDK, but I have no updates with Tesseract

Answer (score 0):

Google Goggles does that... It takes a snapshot, reduces the color depth, scans through various contrast ratios, and exposes letters/words. It then performs a google search on what it found.

Comment: Do you know of anything available for the iPhone?

Answer (score -1):

checkout this article http://www.itwizard.ro/interfacing-cc-libraries-via-jni-example-tesseract-163.html and this example http://code.google.com/p/mezzofanti/

i run it on my G1 and it's OK for single words, but it is very slow if you have 2-3 lines.

maybe with new phones (dual-core ones) you might get several lines in some seconds

Comment: why do I get -1 on this? I don't know, but would like to know. As far as I see it I directly answer the question at least the android half of it.
Maybe someone from mezzofanti not happy with the performance i reported? well, it was the truth at the time, sorry for talling it ;-)